# Is there any way in typescript to make a generic class inherit the properties and methods of the class between angel brackets (<Class>)

Tags: typescript, oop, generics, mongoose, inheritance

I am working on a backend project in which there are multiple entities which share two properties `id` and `description`. So I defined a base class to contain these properties and named it `BaseEntity`

```
class BaseEntity {
   id: string | number;
   description: string;
}
```

I am using MongoDB database and Mongoose orm therefore I am required to define types/interfaces for models and documents. There will be a document type related to every entity type and the document type will contain all properties of its respective entity type. One way of defining document types is to manually define document type for each entity type and other way is (as I feel) to define a generic Document type which would take as type argument one of the entity type and will inherit all of its properties. I am talking of this kind of thing ->

```
class DocumentType<ENTITY_TYPE extends BaseEntity> extends ENTITY_TYPE {
// additional properties
}
```

Now let us assume that there are two types of Entities `User` and `Country` which are defined as follows ->

```
class User extends BaseEntity {
   name: string;
   address: string;
   phoneNumber: number;
}
```

And

```
class Country {
   population: string;
   code: string;
}
```

So according to me class `DocumentType<User>` should have properties `id, description, name, address, phoneNumber` and `DocumentType<Country>` should have properties `id, description, population, code`. Is it possible or  [mixin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) is the only way to go. (I must add that the first way was working a couple of days ago with a typescript warning that I was suppressing through //@ts-ignore but now it is not working at all)

Comment: What is `CLASS_NAME` in your example? is it the name of a class (a string)?

Comment: it is name of a class (like Cat, Dog etc.)

Comment: This can’t work as written since type parameters are erased with the rest of the type system; if you want to extend a class you need to pass that class’s constructor as a value, not just as a type. Looks like you want to implement a *mixin* via a class factory function. Once my internet starts working I’ll demonstrate via code, assuming nobody else does so in the meantime.

Comment: Okay [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WYQndW) shows some code for making a [mixin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) that allows you to extend arbitrary constructors. Is that what you're looking for?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, please consider [edit]ing the code in your question to demonstrate the use cases you're trying to satisfy.

Comment: Does your question now depend on 3rd party libraries like mongoose? If so you should consider tagging it as such, so that people who know about it can notice (I don't know anything about it, so I'd probably disengage). If not you should probably not presume knowledge of it in the question.  It's also very helpful if your provide a [mre] we can just paste into our own IDEs to get to work on the issue, if my [mixin example](https://tsplay.dev/WYQndW) from the previous comment doesn't suffice.  Or maybe it does? How shall we proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz thanks a lot friend. Mixin is new concept to me and I found it to be very interesting. I have also edited the original question as to show my main problem and yes I am using mongoose and I my main problem is related to the it

Comment: Your edit doesn't actually show any code that needs to work differently from my mixin example, and thus doesn't clarify the problem very much. Without a [mre] as *code* I don't know how to proceed.  Oh well.  If you respond explicitly to my requests for code-based clarification, I'll take another look.  Good luck!

Comment: Please [edit] the code in the question instead of describing it verbally in comments.  If you need to talk about `Entity` and `id` and `description` then do so *instead* of `Dog` and `Cat`.  A [mre] should be something present in the question as plaintext.  Please consider reviewing [ask] and what a [mre] is.

Comment: @jcalz  yes, I am also feeling that mixin is the way to go. It would be a great help if you could explain because I am not getting it quite clearly through the documentation. (I am a beginner in asking questions in stack overflow So will try my best editing the code by reading the references)

Comment: I'm not completely sure if I need to modify [my suggested mixin code](https://tsplay.dev/WYQndW) in some way to meet your needs, since there have been quite a few edits and comments from you in the meantime.  I'm also not sure which of my comments you are responding to.  Could you help me by explicitly saying something like either "please write an answer explaining your example solution" or "your example solution doesn't meet my needs" so I can know how to proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz I am really sorry man to bring so much confusion. Please write an answer explaining your example solution.

Comment:  I was in the middle of writing such an answer and now you have changed the example code entirely so that `Dog`, `Cat`, and `Animal` are not present at all. Indeed, the sort of thing you're doing now is what I was asking you to do *if it were necessary to answer the problem*, but I don't understand why you would wait until *after* confirming that my example code was applicable.  It is no longer applicable.  I am going to disengage now to preserve what's left of my sanity.

Comment: @jcalz I am really sorry to destroy your mental peace. I will be really careful in future while asking new questions. But the positive side in this whole scenario is that now I am able to solve my main problem through mixin lol. So thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want something like this

```
class Animal<T extends { [key: string]: boolean }> {
  constructor(private animal: T) {}

  // Accessor methods specific to the class type
  isAnimalType(type: keyof T): boolean {
    return this.animal[type];
  }
}
```

You can now create instances of the **Animal** class with the **Cat** or **Dog** class as the generic parameter, like this:

```
const cat = new Animal<Cat>({ isCat: true });
console.log(cat.isAnimalType('isCat')); // Output: true

const dog = new Animal<Dog>({ isDog: true });
console.log(dog.isAnimalType('isDog')); // Output: true
```